# Adding icons to TabbedMobileApplication in a Flex Mobile project

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, icons, embed

Anyone successfully added an icon to their tabs in `<s:TabbedMobileApplication>` ? I've tried just using something like:

```
<s:ViewNavigator firstView="views.appmobile_HOME" width="100%" height="100%" icon="@Embed(source='../assets/home_icon.png')"/>
```

I've also tried in `<fx:Script>` something like:

```
[Bindable]
[Embed(source="../assets/home_icon.png")]
public static var homeImg:Class;
```

then below added:

```
<s:ViewNavigator firstView="views.appmobile_HOME" width="100%" height="100%" icon="{homeImg}"/>
```

Neither of these methods worked, and to be safe i used the same code to embed an image on the screen and it works!. I just can't seem to get the icons to appear in the tabs!

also note - I was doing all of this in my main mxml file, just incase you're familiar with the Flex Burrito "Mobile application" file structure. And another thing is that I don't get any errors when trying these methods. It lets me compile and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the MAX preview release of the Flex Hero SDK.  I'm not sure if icons were supported at that time.  I verified that this works in the latest build of Hero.  You can access the latest build by signing up for the prerelease program here: http://iamdeepa.com/blog/?p=85

Note: TabbedMobileApplication has been renamed to TabbedViewNavigatorApplication in the latest build.

Comment: All I could find through your links was eventually this page http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+Hero and all that has on it as the most recent build 17689, which is what i have. Where did you get this updated version? (the nightly builds on that page don't support mobile apps so i know it cant be them)

Comment: You'll have to fill out the survey linked in the last paragraph of that blog post: "To request access to the pre-release program, please fill out this quick survey."

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but isn't just going to http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashbuilder_burrito/ and downloading the burrito preview and Flex Hero .... the preview program? It seems weird they would have a preview...within a preview.

Comment: The build listed on Adobe Labs is known as the "Preview Release" of Burrito that was released at Adobe MAX 2010.  That build is publicly available to anyone to download and try.  The "Pre-release Program for Flex Hero & Flash Builder Burrito" is a community of people under NDA that has access to newer builds before the product is officially released.  Along with access to these builds these people provide feedback to the engineering teams about issues they run into.

Comment: I see, well i signed up...hope i get an email. Thanks for showing me.